# Traceback: TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Tags: python

Ok it seems I haven't provided enough information. So the ultimate goal is to run a pingsweep based off of certain subnets. So I create a text file with the subnets and the pingsweep runs and provides output of what all IPs are reachable.

[Here is the pingsweep code](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak4V8AXnd6WjrTfN1ggXWocNzuD3)

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pingsweep1.py", line 118, in <module>
    sub = subnet(line)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `subnet` defined?

Comment: Please describe what is `subnet`, is it a module's function or a subroutine that you wrote?

Comment: Can you maybe show where is subnet? And why you pass `line` as parameter?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You haven't provided enough information.  Whatever `subnet` is, you cannot call it like that. You need to look at its definition or its documentation then use it properly.  Please take the time to read [mcve] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Ok I have added more information.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `subnet` constructor does not require any argument. You need to write:

```
sub = subnet()
```

However, looking at your subnet class, I see that you wrote:

```
class subnet:
      IP = 0
      mask = 0
      index = 0

      def __int__(self,IP):
            sel.ip = long(0)
            m = re.search(r"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/([0-9]+)", IP, flags=0)
            ...
```

So I think is likey that is just a typo. You want `__init__(self, IP)` instead of `__int__(self, IP)` and likely also `self.ip = long(0)` instead of `sel.ip = long(0)`.

Because you wrote `__int__(self, IP)` you were not creating your initializer method. The interpreter was hence using the default constructor, which does not take arguments. I say "default constructor" because your error message tells me that you are using python2, and that is an old-style class as you do not derive it from the top-level `object`.